# mod_rewrite all 80 traffic to 443 with exception

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a vhost running on 443 and 80. On the 80 vhost I have a rule like this.

```
        Redirect permanent / https://localhost
```

I am testing serving a static page in /autos and I want this traffic to not use the redirect rule, i want this page to be served from the 80 vhost without SSL. So i tried setting a RewriteCond and then A RewriteRule for the cond.

```
        RewriteCond %https://localhost !/autos$
        RewriteRule !^/var/www/autos - [C]
```

this is not working cause im likely doing it wrong. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using two vHost definitions - one for http and one for https. 
for plone I use this:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/webalizer(.*) /webalizer$1 [PT]
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:9673/VirtualHostBase/http/www.domain.tld:80/zope/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
```

but perhaps in the https-vHost this ist sufficent too:

```
Redirect permanent /autos http://www.domain.de/autos
```

hth

Comment: thanks for the response, these two options did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to possibilities:

1) Set up a redirect on you Port 80 VirtualHost that ignores the subfolder autos:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^((?!(autos)).)*$ https://your-domain.ain/
```

Note: This does not keep the path in the URL. So http://your-domain.ain/path/to/sth will be redirected to https://your-domain.ain/.

2) IMO the better Solution would be to create a own VirtualHost for the subfolder autos.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName autos.yourdomain.ain
  DocumentRoot /var/www/autos
  ServerAdmin name@domain.com

  # Write a seperate log per Virtualhost
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/autos.access_log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/autos.error_log

  # Maybe you want to put some restrictions on the directory
  <Directory /var/www/autos>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks + Includes
    AllowOverride All
    # Restrict Access to certain IP's (change IP to a real IP or comment out)
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 IP IP IP
    Satisfy ALL
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can find [further information](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/en/vhosts/) on Apache VirtualHosts and [some examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/vhosts/examples.html) in the Apache Manual.

EDIT: For the seperate VHOST you'll need to use NameVirtualHost.
Make sure you have the following Entries in your Apache conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 443
```